# Maximum Likelihood Classification in ENVI

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, envi, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

I am a new ENVI user and I am trying to perform a supervised classification of a Landsat 8 image with the maximum likelihood algorithm.

In order to run the classification, I have to insert a Scale Factor Unit that, for uncalibrated integer data, is equal to the maximum resolution of the sensor (that, for a 16-bit instrument, is 65535).

In this case it works fine, but if I try to perform the classification on an image with an atmospheric correction (Dark Object subtraction), it returns an unclassified image.

The atmospheric correction rescaled the image on lower values, but I can't understand which scale factor I have to insert.

Comment: Unless it has specifically been resealed, data that has been atmospherically corrected to at-sensor-reflectance is floating point [0-1] and not 16-bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably not working because atmospherically corrected images have reflectance values instead of **Digital Numbers**, which is what your 65535 refers to. Since you're not dealing with pixel values anymore, it's not gonna work. What version of ENVI are you using? Version 5.0 sets a default value of 1.0 for Max Likehood classification. I've always used it and never had problems.